# MS SQL server 2016 backwards compatibility

Tags: sql-server

Are there any reported compatibility issues between level 130 to 100?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question with what you acually want to know. You cant migrate a db newer version to older version. You can only change the compabilty mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are reported compatibility issues (difference) between level 100 and 130. Instead of me copy and paste Microsoft document I suggest you consult this document.

[ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level)

I also suggest you list all the changes and test in your development (non prod environment) with simulating production load (covering all aspect of the application).

You might also look at [Microsoft® Data Migration Assistant v3.1.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595)

> Data Migration Assistant (DMA) enables you to upgrade to a modern data
>   platform by detecting compatibility issues that can impact database
>   functionality on your new version of SQL Server. It recommends
>   performance and reliability improvements for your target environment.
>   It allows you to not only move your schema and data, but also
>   uncontained objects from your source server to your target server.

Nice article by Aaron Bertrand:

[Bad habits : Clinging to old compatibility levels](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-old-compatibility-levels/)